# micro water pump set up

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, switch-mode-power-supply

I need to create a water pump system for a modeled water tank.
Now I'm a complete noob so my ignorant self thought I could just buy a small DC pump, a switch and some connectors and off I'd go.
Doing this I depleted the battery in about 4mins of run time.
Connecting these items via a AC/DC converter power supply, resulted in the pump/motor stopping in approx. 2 mins and the wires getting really hot.
Am I going about this all wrong or is there something I'm missing? i.e. relay, motor speed controller, etc.
Can someone help me out with a wiring diagram for this or direct me to were I could learn how to do this? Much appreciated!

Specs of the components I bought:

**Pump:**
    - Rated voltage: DC3V or 4.5V
    - No load of water discharge capacity: 100L / H
    - Load rated current: 0.18A

**Power Supply Adapter**
    - Input: 100V-240V 50/60Hz
    - Output: DC 12V 5A max
    - Output adaptor jack size: 5.5mm x 2.1mm

**Manual Inline DC Power Switch**
   - DC Power Pigtail male/female:2.1x5.5mm
   - Voltage：5-12V
   - Max electric current:2A

Comment: Note the discrepancy: `Pump:
- Rated voltage: DC3V or 4.5V` vs `Power Supply Adapter - Output: DC 12V 5A max`. 12V is a little more than 4.5V. Your pump is dead.

Answer (score 0):

Using a 4.5V pump with a 12V power supply has probably burned out the pump. The voltage of the power supply needs to match the voltage of the pump.

I suggest you find a 12V pump to match your power supply. Or: a get a new 4.5V pump and find a 4.5V power supply to match your pump. (Or 3V. The 3V/4.5V pump will run slower on 3V than on 4.5V)

I don't think you need any extra components.

Comment: Awesome! Multi Voltage adapters seem to be easily available. The only thing that's stalling my choice is the rated wattage (12W vs 30W) and the label that says "check device polarity" before ordering. Both have the polarity listed as - o +.  So the question becomes; Since the pump's connections are two wires (red/black) and both power supplies come with a wire connector, do I have to worry about reversing polarity? I'm assuming I'd be ok with 12W and as long as I connect the red wire to the + and the black wire to the - right?

Comment: @StanDaMan That's correct. And 12W will be enough. Your pump is rated for less than 1W. (It's not a problem that the power supply is 12W and the pump is only 1W)